# Create postgresql command based on DELETE REST call within Django

Tags: django

So I have roughly the following:

```
class exampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       //Custom code
```

The goal is to access the data of the  row that the delete function is gonna delete. Based on this information I need to make some extra PostgreSQL commands before the functions finishes. How can I access this data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ModelViewset?
It’s best to execute your code there.

Something like this:

```
class YourViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        # your code here
        super().perform_destroy(instance)
```